TypeError: RepositoryClientConfig is not a constructor
I am using node.js version 21.7.1 and graphdb version 10.0.6  to query the 'movies' repository that is in the interactive guide, I am using that as a test. My question is can I getting an error that says (TypeError: RepositoryClientConfig is not a constructor) however it states in the documentation that it is a constructor
below is the code;
const { ServerClient, ServerClientConfig, RepositoryClientConfig } = require('graphdb').server;
const { RDFMimeType, SparqlJsonResultParser, GetQueryPayload, QueryType } = require('graphdb').http;

const serverConfig = new ServerClientConfig('http://localhost:7200')
  .setTimeout(5000)
  .setHeaders({
    'Accept': RDFMimeType.SPARQL_RESULTS_JSON
  })
  .setKeepAlive(true);

const server = new ServerClient(serverConfig);

const repositoryClientConfig = new RepositoryClientConfig(['http://localhost:7200/movies']);
const repositoryClient = server.getRepository(repositoryClientConfig);
repositoryClient.registerParser(new SparqlJsonResultParser());

const payload = new GetQueryPayload()
  .setQuery('select * where {?s ?p ?o}')
  .setQueryType(QueryType.SELECT)
  .setResponseType(RDFMimeType.SPARQL_RESULTS_JSON)
  .setLimit(100);

repositoryClient.query(payload).then((stream) => {
  stream.on('data', (bindings) => {
    console.log(bindings);
  });
  stream.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Query execution completed');
  });
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error executing query:', error);
});

I am getting the error code
TypeError: RepositoryClientConfig is not a constructor

I used  the 'getRepository' method of the 'ServerClient' instance, passing the repository ID as a string,
code below:
const { ServerClient, ServerClientConfig } = require('graphdb').server;
const { RDFMimeType, SparqlJsonResultParser, GetQueryPayload, QueryType } = require('graphdb').http;

const serverConfig = new ServerClientConfig('http://localhost:7200')
  .setTimeout(5000)
  .setHeaders({
    'Accept': RDFMimeType.SPARQL_RESULTS_JSON
  })
  .setKeepAlive(true);

const server = new ServerClient(serverConfig);

const repositoryClient = server.getRepository('movies3', { readOnly: true });
repositoryClient.registerParser(new SparqlJsonResultParser());

const payload = new GetQueryPayload()
  .setQuery('select * where {?s ?p ?o}')
  .setQueryType(QueryType.SELECT)
  .setResponseType(RDFMimeType.SPARQL_RESULTS_JSON)
  .setLimit(100);

repositoryClient.query(payload).then((stream) => {
  stream.on('data', (bindings) => {
    console.log(bindings);
  });
  stream.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Query execution completed');
  });
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error executing query:', error);
});

And this the error I am getting

Error: RepositoryClientConfig is required parameter!


We assume you have a running GDB instance on 'localhost' and port '7200', that has at least a repository "movies".
Note that the method that you'll have to configure the repositories accepts an array of repository names.
const { ServerClient, ServerClientConfig, RepositoryClientConfig } = require('graphdb').server;

const { RDFMimeType, SparqlJsonResultParser, GetQueryPayload, QueryType } = require('graphdb').http;

 

const serverConfig = new ServerClientConfig('http://localhost:7200')

  .setTimeout(5000)

  .setHeaders({

    'Accept': RDFMimeType.SPARQL_RESULTS_JSON

  })

  .setKeepAlive(true);

 

const server = new ServerClient(serverConfig);

 

const repositoryClientConfig = new RepositoryClientConfig('http://localhost:7200')

                                                    .setEndpoints(['http://localhost:7200/repositories/movies']);

const repositoryClient = await server.getRepository('movies', repositoryClientConfig);

repositoryClient.registerParser(new SparqlJsonResultParser());

 

  const payload = new GetQueryPayload()

  .setQuery('select * where {?s ?p ?o}')

  .setQueryType(QueryType.SELECT)

  .setResponseType(RDFMimeType.SPARQL_RESULTS_JSON)

  .setLimit(100);

 

repositoryClient.query(payload).then((stream) => {

  stream.on('data', (bindings) => {

    console.log(bindings);

 

});

  stream.on('end', () => {

    console.log('Query execution completed');

  });

}).catch((error) => {

  console.error('Error executing query:', error);

});

